# (unity)Is there a way to set the position of every particle in a particle system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

So i want to make like an aura around the player, like in warcraft 3 or path of exile, etc, using a particle system, and when the character is idle it works perfectly fine. Thing is when it isnt idle.

I've tried changing the particle system position itself using Update(), but that doesnt really affect the position of the particles. What i need is to set each one of them to the players position.

Is there a way to set the particles to the position of the player?(or any position at all)

Thanks

Comment: Is the particle attached to the player? if so, it should follow the player. Is is set to local position? When SimulationSpace is set to world space and they are attached to player, particles stick to the position they were created, so if the player moves, it acts as a trail. If set to local space, then all particles are following player movement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### To answer your problem

You can change the [`ParticleSystem.simulationSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-simulationSpace.html)

> Controls whether particles are animated in the parent object’s local space (therefore moving with the parent object), in the world space, or relative to a custom object (moving with a custom object of your choosing).

to [`ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Local`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Local.html)

> Simulate particles in local space

Either via the Inspector of the [Main Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysMainModule.html)

[image]

or via code like

```
GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main.simulationSpace = ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Local;
```

---

#### To answer your question title

Yes. You can get the particles via [`ParticleSystem.GetParticles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.GetParticles.html), change their [`ParticleSystem.Particle.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Particle-position.html) and then write them back into the system using [`ParticleSystem.SetParticles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.SetParticles.html)

```
var particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[theParticleSystem.main.maxParticles];
var currentAmount = theParticleSystem.GetParticles(particles)

// Change only the particles that are alive
for (int i = 0; i < currentAmount; i++)
{
    particles[i].position = XYZ;
}

// Apply the particle changes to the Particle System
theParticleSystem.SetParticles(particles, currentAmount);
```

Comment: Thanks! the last one was the one I expected as an answer. Both are equally useful for me, but later on the second one will be for a better use of each individual particle.